# Send email with localhost on ubuntu with PHP (possible over external mail server)

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu, sendmail

I installed Ubuntu desktop 12.04 64bit on my laptop. I used these commands to install a simple web server:

```
apt-get install apache2

apt-get install php5

apt-get install mysql-server
```

All is working fine for the sugar crm that I want to be hosted locally. However getting email to be sent out is a real struggle I tried exim4 sendmail and postfix.

I configured and tried a lot so I guess telling you what i tried to make it work would only cause confusion.

I am a newby to ubuntu and the command line, any guidance in getting mail to be sent out is very much appreciated!

Comment: This probably better belongs to askubuntu.com

Answer (score 6):

I installed ssmtp:

```
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
```

and used my gmail credentials in the:

```
gksu gedit /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

.

```
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
#root=postmaster
root=****@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
#mailhub=mail
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

AuthUser=****@gmail.com
AuthPass=****
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname
#hostname=MyMediaServer.home
hostname=****@gmail.com

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES
```

All works fine now!

Comment: awesome its working and i made it as an article here. http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/03/send-e-mail-localhost-ubuntu-php/

Answer (score 1):

Please do following steps to send mail from *localhost* on **Ubuntu/Linux** through **gmail** :-

For that you need to install **`msmtp`** on Linux/Ubuntu server.

Gmail uses ***https://*** (it's hyper text secure) so you need install `ca-certificates`

```
~$ sudo apt-get install msmtp ca-certificates
```

It will take few seconds to install `msmtp` package.

Now you have to create configuration file(**`msmtprc`**) using , gedit editor.

```
~$ sudo gedit /etc/msmtprc
```

Now you have to copy and paste following code in gedit (*file you created with above command*)

```
defaults
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
auth on
user MY_GMAIL_ID@gmail.com
password MY_GMAIL_PASSSWORD
from MY_GMAIL_ID@gmail.com
logfile /var/log/msmtp.log
```

Don't forget to replace **MY_GMAIL_ID** with your "*gmail id*" and **MY_GMAIL_PASSSWORD** with your "*gmail password*" in above lines of code.

Now create `msmtp.log` as

```
~$ sudo touch /var/log/msmtp.log
```

You have to make this file readable by anyone with

```
~$ sudo chmod 0644 /etc/msmtprc
```

Now Enable sendmail log file as writable with

```
~$ sudo chmod 0777 /var/log/msmtp.log
```

Your configuration for gmail's SMTP is now ready. Now send one test email as

```
~$ echo -e "Subject: Test Mail\r\n\r\nThis is my first test email." |msmtp --debug --from=default -t MY_GMAIL_ID@gmail.com
```

Please check your Gmail inbox.

For sending mail with php please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969783/phpubuntu-send-email-using-gmail-form-localhost